# Chaining focus( ) and blur( ) in jQuery input field event processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery i've seen the blur( ) chained to the focus( ) like this:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Why doesn't blur( ) execute immediately after the focus event is fired? When blur( ) is chained to focus( ) it doesn't execute until after the field loses focus yet because it is chained I would think it would fire immediately after the focus event is fired even though the input field has not yet lost focus.

Comment: It's because you're assigning event handler functions which run when those events occur, not defining functions to be executed immediately in sequence. In addition, with regard to the specific example in the question, you should really be creating this effect in CSS, not JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought that might be the case, but when chaining non-event functions they always execute in quick succession.  Why is it different with event processing?

Comment: You *are* executing the *event binding* immediately.   The events themselves fire when they fire.

Comment: @freedomn-m . Thank you!  That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @RMH glad to help, please mark the answer as accepted (an upvote would be nice as well :) )

Comment: @freedomn-m I would love to mark your comment as the answer but there is no mechanism that I can see to do that.

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when chaining non-event functions they always execute in quick succession

In this case, they functions *are* running immediately, but these functions are *event bindings*, not the *events*.

So the blur *event* is not chained to the *focus* event, only the event handlers are added via chaining.

---

Note that chaining just allows for functions to be called one after the other without interim variables.  There's no difference in your code from:

```
var inp = $("input");
inp.focus(function() { $(this).css("background-color", "blue"); });
inp.blur(function() { $(this).css("background-color", "red"); });
```